# Error while setting up docker dev env

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup docker dev env on my Mac laptop. I am following the intructions described here. https://docs.docker.com/opensource/project/set-up-dev-env/

Whenever I run `make shell` command. I get the following error.

```
gpg: requesting key F6B0FC61 from hkp server p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
?: p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
```

Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Is your laptop able to connect Internet?

Comment: Yes. I am able to post questions and comment on stackoverflow, so I am pretty sure I am connected to the internet.

Comment: So I think that the VM can not connect Internet. You should access the VM and try to do something to test the internet connection

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue was but it seems `docker-machine upgrade` did the trick for me. Thanks.